# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript

¿Qué está pasando?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="asignar.js"></script>
    <title>Asignar</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Est es el número original: </p><input type="number" id="original">
    <p>Est es el número modificado: </p><input type="number" id="modificado">

</body>
</html>
```

Y el contenido de **asignar.js** es:

```
var numero = 7;

document.getElementById("original").value=numero;

mod(numero);

document.getElementById("modificado").value=numero;

function mod(a){
    a=8;
}
```

> ERROR: document.getElementById("original").value = numero;

Answer (score 4):

Es porque estás cargando el archivo javascript antes de que el DOM haya cargado por completo. Lo que podrías hacer es agregar un evento que escuche cuando el DOM haya sido cargado y ejecutar tu código.

Podrías hacer esto:

```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      var numero = 7;
      document.getElementById("original").value=numero;
      mod(numero);
      document.getElementById("modificado").value=numero;
      function mod(a){
        a=8;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Estás cargando el código de JavaScript antes que existan en el DOM los `<input>`, puedes pasar el archivo .js al final del archivo (del body, más precisamente):

```
<body>
  <input type="number" id="original">
  <input type="number" id="modificado">

  <script src="asignar.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución posible, sería agregar defer en la carga de tu script.

```
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="asignar.js"></script>
```